# Calculate quadratic function from given points in 2 dimensions

Tags: quadratics

The quadratic function can be defined as 
$z = a+b*x+c*y+d*x^2 +e*x*y+f*y^2$
But how to find the 6 coefficients from given truples $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$?
I hope that there is a not too difficult solution. Can anybody give me a reference? In opposite to e.g. solving a cubic equation in 1D I found nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when formatting your questions.

Comment: Each tuple gives you an equation in six variables.

Comment: You can write the equation in determinant form directly from the tuples.

Comment: Thanks!! It seems solving the linear equations is not so difficult, and most of my expected problems pop up later (or earlier, e.g. on chosing the 6 points).

Comment: I solved the problem for myself now. It was easier than expected, thanks for support.